# Flyway problems configuration with Spring Boot 3.1.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

I have come across with a problem of connection Flyway to my Spring Boot Application.
Once I launch my App I am getting this

The following method did not exist:

```
'org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration.oracleSqlplus(boolean)'
```

The calling method's class, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration, was loaded from the following location:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/3.1.0/spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.0.jar!/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class
```

The called method's class, org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/flywaydb/flyway-core/9.22.2/flyway-core-9.22.2.jar!/org/flywaydb/core/api/configuration/FluentConfiguration.class
```

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration: file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/flywaydb/flyway-core/9.22.2/flyway-core-9.22.2.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration and org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration

Here comes my POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
  
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.33</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.flywaydb/flyway-mysql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-mysql</artifactId>
    <version>9.22.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Maybe someone has faced with such issue and knows how to fix it? If I really need to correct the classpath of my application so that it contains compatible versions, could someone give me a tip how to do it?
Thanks in advance.

In the application.properties I have mentioned following:

```
spring.flyway.enabled = true
spring.flyway.locations = classpath:db/migration
spring.flyway.baselineOnMigrate = true 
spring.flyway.schemas= ...
spring.flyway.url = ...
spring.flyway.user= ...
spring.flyway.password= ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Is there a feature of Flyway 9.22.2 that you need? If not, I believe the issue is spring-boot-3.1.x only supports Flyway `9.16.3`. You can see a curated list of spring-boot dependency versions [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/dependency-versions.html).

As a general rule, if the library you need is [specified in the curated spring-boot dependency list](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/dependency-versions.html), you're better off using the version supplied by Spring because that version will have been vetted to work with that version of spring-boot. Assuming you don't need that specific version of Flyway, you can leverage the "approved" version from spring-boot by deleting the `<version>` tags in your pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  
  <!-- dependency versions will be inherited from the parent pom -->
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

<!-- Other aspects of the pom have been omitted for clarity -->
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-mysql</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You can also remove the `<version>` tag for the `mysql-connector-j` dependency as well.

Also, it looks like the Spring team is targeting [Flyway 9.22.x for spring-boot 3.2.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/37315)